# Change option in select using Ruby Mechanize

Tags: javascript, ruby, select, mechanize

I am using Mechanize gem.

I am trying to select and submit an option on a web page :

```
<select class="transform" onchange="if(this.value != '')document.location.href=this.value;">
```

This select is not part of a form. It is just a select that triggers a javascript action onchange. How can I set the select to the option I want and trigger the js onchange ?

Comment: AFAIK, mechanize doesn't support javascript.  You might want to look at selenium, watir, or something that drives a browser.

Comment: while @orde is correct, that mechanize does not support javascript, This js is simple enough in functionality that you could just navigate using the value of the select since that's all the js is doing anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the option looks like this:

```
option = page.at('option[text()=foo]')
```

You would do the action (change location to the option's value) with:

```
page = agent.get option[:value]
```

Comment: I am sorry but I dont get what you are doing here. Is the first line setting the option to the desired value ?

Comment: No, the first lines selects the option by it's text.